# Restore Magento catalog

Tags: magento-1.9, database, import

We have a Magento 1.9.0 and a recent data upload messed up a lot of our product data.
We have a backup database from earlier this morning.
We don't want to restore the entire database as we have had plenty of orders since.
What tables should we grab from the backup database in order to restore JUST the catalog?

Answer (score 2):

I followed this article http://blog.briteskies.com/blog/recover-your-magento-catalog-from-a-mysql-dump

Everything worked out great, but the author of that post only recovered certain tables and all our inventory was off.

I went back and grabbed all the tables that begin with catalog and it worked like a charm

```
mysqldump -u username -p password database_name  catalog_category_anc_categs_index_idx  catalog_category_anc_categs_index_tmp catalog_category_anc_products_index_idx  catalog_category_anc_products_index_tmp   catalog_category_entity   catalog_category_entity_datetime   catalog_category_entity_decimal   catalog_category_entity_int   catalog_category_entity_text   catalog_category_entity_varchar   catalog_category_flat_store_1   catalog_category_flat_store_2   catalog_category_flat_store_3   catalog_category_flat_store_4   catalog_category_flat_store_5   catalog_category_product   catalog_category_product_index   catalog_category_product_index_enbl_idx   catalog_category_product_index_enbl_tmp   catalog_category_product_index_idx   catalog_category_product_index_tmp   catalog_compare_item   catalog_eav_attribute   catalog_product_bundle_option   catalog_product_bundle_option_value   catalog_product_bundle_price_index   catalog_product_bundle_selection   catalog_product_bundle_selection_price   catalog_product_bundle_stock_index   catalog_product_enabled_index   catalog_product_entity   catalog_product_entity_datetime   catalog_product_entity_decimal   catalog_product_entity_gallery   catalog_product_entity_group_price   catalog_product_entity_int   catalog_product_entity_media_gallery   catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value   catalog_product_entity_text   catalog_product_entity_tier_price   catalog_product_entity_varchar   catalog_product_flat_1   catalog_product_flat_2   catalog_product_flat_3   catalog_product_index_eav   catalog_product_index_eav_decimal   catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_idx   catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_tmp   catalog_product_index_eav_idx   catalog_product_index_eav_tmp   catalog_product_index_group_price   catalog_product_index_price   catalog_product_index_price_bundle_idx   catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_idx   catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_tmp   catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_idx   catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_tmp   catalog_product_index_price_bundle_tmp   catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_idx   catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_tmp   catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_idx   catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_tmp   catalog_product_index_price_downlod_idx   catalog_product_index_price_downlod_tmp   catalog_product_index_price_final_idx   catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp   catalog_product_index_price_idx   catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_idx   catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_tmp   catalog_product_index_price_opt_idx   catalog_product_index_price_opt_tmp   catalog_product_index_price_tmp   catalog_product_index_tier_price   catalog_product_index_website   catalog_product_link   catalog_product_link_attribute   catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal   catalog_product_link_attribute_int   catalog_product_link_attribute_varchar   catalog_product_link_type   catalog_product_option   catalog_product_option_price   catalog_product_option_title   catalog_product_option_type_price   catalog_product_option_type_title   catalog_product_option_type_value   catalog_product_relation   catalog_product_super_attribute   catalog_product_super_attribute_label   catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing   catalog_product_super_link   catalog_product_website   cataloginventory_stock   cataloginventory_stock_item   cataloginventory_stock_status   cataloginventory_stock_status_idx   cataloginventory_stock_status_tmp   catalogrule   catalogrule_affected_product   catalogrule_customer_group   catalogrule_group_website   catalogrule_product   catalogrule_product_price   catalogrule_website   catalogsearch_fulltext   catalogsearch_query   catalogsearch_report   catalogsearch_result > catalog_export2.sql
```

Comment: In my case, to make the site work properly, I had to restore also the 'core_url_rewrite' table to restore the correct products' urls

Answer (score 0):

That's a difficult situation. You could try moving a partial database (probably everything but the customers and orders) but you might be introducing long-term instability.

How about this approach: spin up your store in a development environment, then try exporting all the products and categories to CSV, then using something like Magmi to re-import them into the latest version of the database.